# Popup Rotator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need of a simple popup rotator for open 1 different popup with 1 click on Alertbox.
I find this code that could be perfect if works...
With 1 click on alertbox using `window.open` I open `ad_rotator.php`

```
<center>
<?php

$fcontents = join ('', file ('banner_ads.txt'));
$s_con = split("~",$fcontents);

$banner_no = rand(0,(count($s_con)-1));
echo $s_con[$banner_no];
?>
</center>
```

In the banner_ads.txt I add my popup code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pmauid = 'Numbers';
var pmawid = 'Numbers';
var fq = '0';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mypopnetwork.com"></script>
```

but nothing is open, empty window. 
Maybe the problem is that this popup code is programming for starting from page and not from external file.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Could you put this on a jsfiddle?

Comment: Popup code can't because then it count poor traffic in my sistem. For now the better method is simply change popup code in my page but I not think can be difficult create a automatic system for change popupcode.